Why can't we say “How hard is to earn money”?
Why can't we say “How hard is to earn money”?

It is a question of pleonastic “it”!

Thanks for answer. can we say: how hard is earning money?

Note: “It is hard to earn money”, “How hard it is to earn money!!”
